# Don't understand what does mean truncated class file

Tags: java

Please, tell me how can I solve my problem. When I get such output, what does it mean?

```
julia@julia-Aspire-5680 ~/zagruzchik $ java Loader3 HelloWorld 0    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class   file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
at Loader4.runClass(Loader3.java:52)
    at Loader3.main(Loader3.java:10)
```

Comment: Your class file is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

File you are trying to interpret is not a valid class file. Are you surely compiling the right file?

Comment: I haven't compiled, because I have got this file from another by Caesar shipher. I have class file, take byte code and summ every number with 3. My program should decode this file (deduct 3) and run without compiling. Is it possible?

Comment: @JuliaKolesnikova I think that you're messing it up that way so it isn't able to run. You're changin the meaning of a whole file with your manipulation Don't take me for granted because I'm not very experienced with that kind of file manipulation, hope I helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Recompile the java file and try. Looks like your class file is corrupted.

Please refer to this link as well:
https://community.oracle.com/thread/2074437?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I haven't compiled, because I have got this file from another by Caesar shipher. I have class file, take byte code and summ every number with 3. My program should decode this file (deduct 3) and run without compiling. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error when the disk ran out of space in the middle of a compilation. Some of the generated .class files were corrupt

Answer (score 0):

I had same problems on windows 7/64, the problem was apparently a main method which was commented out, i removed the comment including the main method and run fine.